# How to map one csv content to another csv content in unix shell

Tags: shell, csv, mapping, split

I have a csv with the following inputs

```
Product1,Comp1|Comp2|Comp3|...,Owner1|Owner2|||...
Product2,Comp1|Comp2|Comp3|...,Owner1|||Owner3|...
Product3,CompX
```

I put .... to indicate variable no of Comp list seperated by |, We can assume that for every Comp csv file will have a owner info if available otherwise it will be blank,

Now i need to generate an xml in the following format

```
<product='Product1' Comp='Comp1' Owner='Owner1' />
<product='Product1' Comp='Comp2' Owner='Owner2' />
<product='Product1' Comp='Comp3' Owner='' />
.
.
.

<product='Product2' Comp='Comp1' Owner='Owner1' />
<product='Product2' Comp='Comp2' Owner='' />
<product='Product2' Comp='Comp3' Owner='Owner3' />
.
.
.
<product='Product3' Comp='CompX' Owner='' />
```

I wrote the following code for it.

```
ifs=$IFS
IFS='
'

for line in `cat input.csv`;do
# echo $line
prd=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f1`
components=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f2`
owners=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f3`

# echo $components

IFS='|'
i=0
for comp in `echo $components`;do
   i=`expr $i + 1`
   IFS=$ifs
   owner=`echo $owners | cut -d'|' -f$i`
   echo "<product='$prd' Comp='$comp' Owner='$owner' />"
done
done
```

Which is not working properly. Can anybody suggest me other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quit sure about the `...` notation. I'd use a single for loop to handle all the inner column logic, and use a simple `while read` method to handle the line-by-line.

```sh
while read LINE
do
        COLUMNS=(`echo $LINE | tr ',' ' '`)
        COMPS=(`echo ${COLUMNS[1]} | tr '|' ' '`)
        for (( i=0 ; i<${#COMPS[@]} ; i++ ))
        do
                OWNER=`echo ${COLUMNS[2]} | awk '{split($0,owner,"|"); print owner[$1]}'
                echo "<product='${COLUMNS[0]}' Comp='${COMPS[$i]}' Owner='$OWNER' />"
        done
done < input.csv
```

Comment: The output i am getting is <product='Product1' Comp='Comp1' Owner='Owner1' />
<product='Product1' Comp='Comp2' Owner='Owner2' />
*' />duct='Product1' Comp='Comp3' Owner='...
<product='Product2' Comp='Comp1' Owner='Owner1' />
<product='Product2' Comp='Comp2' Owner='Owner3' />
*' />duct='Product2' Comp='Comp3' Owner='...
it is printing some lines not properly, I marked then with *

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Adjusted script to map owner of comps by using awk to search for matching index

Comment: One suggestion while copying the content from windows to unix is to make sure to delete \r charecters.